# Replacing a char at provided index in a string

Tags: python

So I have this string: `"My Wurds"` and I'd like to replace the `u` at index `4` with `o`. what is the proper Python way to do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: You have tried exactly zero things, right?

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you want to replace the 'u' because it is a 'u' or because it is in 4th position?

Comment: Because of the index

Answer (score 1):

You could build a new string using slices:

```
s = "My Wurds"
t = s[:4] + "o" + s[5:]
```

Comment: -1. it only works for this particular case when input string is "My Wurds". I don't think it is an intent of any program to hardcode input values

Comment: @Artemious It really isn't difficult to take his example and encode it into a function, t = s[:index] + value + s[index+1:], really no reason for down-voting.

Comment: @Artemious It is: `Because of the index – Pavel Zagalsky`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of `u` where you need to replace with `o`, a pretty straight approach would be:

```
s[:4] + s[4:].replace('u', 'o', 1)
```

`replace('u', 'o', 1)` will ensure replace of only first occurance.